How is Newton's First Law equivalent to the postulate that inertial systems exist?
Some of the modern mechanics textbooks provide further comments on Newton's laws and aim to refine them. To understand these modern interpretations, I'm referring to "Introduction to Mechanics" by K&K and "Analytical Mechanics" by Fasano and Marmi.
In K&K's introduction to the first law, we begin with an experimental setup consisting of a linear air track. The air jets in this system eliminate friction and the involvement of other forces except that which we apply. So, when we push the rider, we find that once we're not touching it, it maintains a uniform velocity.
We've implicitly assumed a coordinate system that is fixed with respect to the track (because we're stationary when looking at the rider). So, what Newton's first law is saying is that we can always find a coordinate system where an isolated body moves without acceleration. Our coordinate system was stationary with respect to the track, but we could, in contrast, be moving with constant velocity in reference to the track and we'll still observe that the rider has no acceleration. The fact that we can find a coordinate system with respect to which an isolated body moves without acceleration is Newton's law.
Analytical Mechanics also makes a similar formulation. It first defines an inertial observer as "any observer for whom, at every time and for any kinematic state, an isolated point particle has zero acceleration". Then, Newton's first law is simply that "There exists an inertial observer".
However, suppose now that the rider on the linear track is accelerating when I'm not touching it. This is of course, a violation of the first law as we typically think of it. However, the interpretations provided in these texts seem to condone such behavior. Suppose the rider has an acceleration $a$. Then, there indeed exists a coordinate system under which it would appear to have zero acceleration. Just make this coordinate accelerate in the same direction with magnitude $a$. Then, by the definition given by Farsano and Mami of an inertial observer, our coordinate system is inertial and the first law holds, even though it clearly doesn't. How, then, is the interpretation that "inertial systems exist" equivalent to Newton's first law?

Suppose an isolated particle had zero acceleration with respect to a non inertial frame. Then, assuming the isolation of a particle is a frame independent notion (distances between two objects at the same moment of time are frame invariant in Newtonian mechanics), it would imply that the same particle, despite still being isolated, has a non zero acceleration with respect to an inertial frame ( as when you switch from a non inertial to an inertial frame, you add an acceleration to particles). Since this implication is in contradiction with Newton's first law, we conclude that the premises
is invalid.
So Newton's first law, along with some assumptions about distance invariance and the definition of a non inertial frame (in terms of an inertial frame), implies that an isolated particle cannot have a zero acceleration with respect to a non inertial frame.
Additionally, if you didn't know you were in a non inertial frame, and you observed an apparently isolated particle moving with a constant velocity, you can just throw a second a particle with some initial velocity. Unless you are freely falling under uniform gravity, this experiment will always determine that you are in a non inertial frame, as the second particle you threw would not maintain its velocity.

How exactly do you define inertial and non-inertial frames? The books I'm referring to define an inertial frame as one where an isolated body appears to have no acceleration. So, these frames aren't defined with any reference to their own velocity/acceleration.

@Aryaan I am defining an inertial frame same as the book does, and a non inertial frame as a frame which has non zero acceleration with respect to an inertial frame

How then does the statement "Suppose an isolated particle has zero acceleration with respect to a non inertial frame" make sense? By definition, wouldn't the frame be inertial since it's observing an isolated particle with zero acceleration?

@Aryaan i am using a "proof by contradiction". Assume that that were true, and arrive at a contradiction.

@Aryaan also note that the definition of an inertial frame is that any isolated particle must have zero acceleration. So the assumption "assume a single particle has zero acceleration wrt a non inertial frame" does not immediately contradict an inertial frame's definition, but it does lead to another contradiction which I've shown
